# What species is this turtle in Houston?

Tags: species-identification, herpetology

This turtle was displaced by hurricane Harvey in Houston, Texas, USA (Buffalo  Bayou and Dunlavy). It appears to be a snapper. Can someone identify the exact species?

[image: turtle]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's an [Alligator snapping turtle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alligator_snapping_turtle), *Macrochelys temminckii*.

Here is another picture of it (from the same Wikipedia page linked above):

[image]

It should not be mistaken for the [Common snapping turtle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_snapping_turtle), which belongs to a different Genus.

There is a problem, though: in 2014 Thomas et al. divided the Genus *Macrochelys* (which originally contained only one species, *Macrochelys temminckii*) in three species: *Macrochelys temminckii* itself, *Macrochelys suwanniensis* and *Macrochelys apalachicolae*.

Therefore, narrowing this down to the exact species (according to the current taxonomy of the Genus) may be way more complicated.

---

Source:

- Thomas, T, Granatosky, M, Bourque, J, Krysko, K, Moler, P, Gamble, T, Suarez, Leone, E, Enge, K, & Roman, J, 2014. Taxonomic assessment of Alligator Snapping Turtles (Chelydridae: Macrochelys), with the description of two new species from the southeastern United States. Zootaxa 3786 (2): 141–165

Comment: Above answer is correct but the other two recently differentiated species are both East of Texas, so this is for sure temminckii.